# OCaml in enterprise stack

Tags: ocaml, enterprise

I'm trying to figure out how OCaml is represented in enterprise technology stack. For example,  Is there in Ocaml own enterprise message queue or workflow engine?

So, can anybody advice me frameworks for OCaml from the following aspects:

- Workflow engine
- Service bus
- Message Queue
- ORM
- HTTP Server

Update #1: Workflow Engine

- en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_engine
- http://www.jboss.org/drools - one of implementations in Java technology stack.
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation - implementation of WE in .NET technology stack

Comment: How does an enterprise message queue differ from an ordinary message queue?

Comment: Drools isn't workflow engine, it's rules engine, for full list of open source workflow engines for java see this page http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps [ocamlnet](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/ocamlnet.html) answers partly to your questions. If you want to code web server (or services) in Ocaml, consider also [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/)

(and I don't really understand the *entreprise stack* sentence; for me it is a marketing buzz word without a clearly defined technical content)

I have no idea of what a "list item" is for you. I am not sure to understand "workflow engine" neither.

And the [Ocaml Hump](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.cgi) is a nice place to find Ocaml software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you regarding the term 'enterprise'. But I had to find one very capacious word which encompasses several very common issues we face with in enterprise application development

Comment: Workflow Engine - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow_engine.
http://www.jboss.org/drools - one of implementations in Java technology stack.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation - implementation of WE in .NET technology stack

Answer (score 6):

For message queues: [NetAMQP](http://oss.wink.com/netamqp/).

For an ORM: maybe [Macaque](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/macaque/) can fit here. It's not exactly like what you can find elsewhere, but it fits the functional spirit.

For an HTTP server: [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org). It also includes a framework for developing web applications (client and server) entirely in OCaml.  [Ocamlnet](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/ocamlnet.html) also provides libraries useful to write CGI applications as well as an Apache connector.

Answer (score 4):

- [ocamlmq](http://eigenclass.org/R2/writings/ocamlmq-release) is a pure OCaml STOMP message broker written by Mauricio Fernandez
- [ocamlnet](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-3.4.1/doc/html-main/Intro.html) is a high-performance evented system layer for network programming, by Gerd Stolpmann. Besides a complete HTTP server, it contains a:
- [Sun RPC](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-3.4.1/doc/html-main/Intro.html#ch_cs) service layer that lets you transparently bind to fault-tolerant services across the network by using a locator

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers already posted, see [Opa](http://opalang.org/)

It's a web development langauge/framework written in OCaml. It takes a unique approach in that the server, database and app are all in one executable.